# UIButton selected not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

Simple, but not working! Can someone please help? All I want is to just toggle the selection of a UIButton, with the code below:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([self.mybutton isSelected]) {
        NSLog(@"selected");
        [self.mybutton setSelected:NO];
    } else {
       NSLog(@"not selected");
        [self.mybutton setSelected:YES];
    }
    NSLog([self.mybutton isSelected] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
}
```

Though I press the button any number of times, every time, what gets printed is 'not selected' and 'No'.
Why isn't the UIButton getting set to 'selected' state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code seems to be correct, you can make it simpler this way:

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Why your code is not working properly? Probably `self.mybutton` is `nil` (you can check that out). Check your outlet connection and the property definition...
Ref.: Sending a message not a `nil` object, returns either `nil` or the default value if it's a simple type (0 for `int`, `NO` for `BOOL`, etc..)

Comment: I am not sure if the question has been edited after you had answered it but;
If mybutton were nil then the target method does not get called. He would not get nslog.

Comment: That's not true.. The `IBOutlet` and the `IBAction` are different and independent when connecting them though the Interface Builder. I bet this is totally the case - the connection with `mybutton` property is not ok.

Comment: Upps my mistake. You are right. I am not a Interface builder likely man +1 for pointing that out :)

Comment: +1 Thanks! That was the issue! How silly! I had connected IBAction in IB, but not IBOutlet !